# Windows 7 MSDN Expiration

Tags: windows-7, development-environment, msdn

I have read that the public beta version of Windows 7 has an expiration on it, but does the MSDN Premium also expire on the same date?

And if so, do you think that we might see a newer version before the expiration on MSDN?

For the speed improvements alone I am contemplating moving my development PC to Windows 7 over Windows Vista, stability issues aside, I am an early adopter anyway and expect issues with beta operating systems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing not programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MSDN version of Windows 7 says:

"Evaluation copy.  Expires 7/1/2009 5:59 PM"

I imagine that they'll have another version posted by then - mabye even the RTM if we get really lucky.

Answer (score 2):

As I have done for a while with VStudio 10 CTP, you have the possibility to change the clock on you virtual machine when you start it. In my case, when I lunche VS10, I settle my virtual machine's clock to 11/1/2008 - and it's still running !

Comment: i don't like the idea of bypassing expirations, it seems like a pain in the rear.  Also i am thinking about doing this as a primary OS, not as a VM.

Comment: Though it's annoying (especially if you're using it as your full-time machine), this might be the only way to do it.

Comment: do we know if the win 7 beta from msdn expires though?

Comment: I have found it to remove the expiry date. Not sure if it is a microsoft patch or not (I did not install it). http://customizewindows7.com/2009/01/remove-1st-july-expiry-date-windows-7-beta-build-6170000-plus-patch/